# sql - way to only update 1 (the first the query finds) value when i got 2 or more with the same value?

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I have this code in java to replace the minimum score in my highscore table but if i got more two or more with the same score and it is the minimum score in the table it will replace all of them, but i only wanna replace 1 of them (anyone of them).

> PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Highscore SET Name = ?, 
>      Score = ?, Time = ?, Level = ? WHERE Score = (SELECT TOP 1 Score FROM Highscore ORDER BY Score      >    ASC)");
>
> preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
>
> preparedStatement.setInt(2, score);
>
> preparedStatement.setInt(3, time);
>
> preparedStatement.setString(4, level);
>
> int updateCount = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

Hey i was woundering if there is a way to only update 1 (the first the query finds) value when i got 2 or more with the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem like a question related to Java but rather one related to database design.

Colloquially,  every row in a table must be uniquely identifiable (according to relational model theory); this is called data integrity. The easiest way to achieve this is to add an attribute serving as primary key in your table.

Commonly, the primary key is an integer number starting at 1 and is incremented for each additional row you add in your table.

Now to come to your question: Simply add a primary key to your table and then your 'where'-condition can be  modified as:

```
UPDATE Highscore 
SET Name = ?, Score = ?, Time = ?, Level = ? 
WHERE PrimaryKey = (SELECT TOP 1 PrimaryKey FROM Highscore ORDER BY Score)
```

Note that the 'where'-condition gets the primary key, called 'PrimaryKey' for simplicty, from your scores and then that will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to split your query? So you get the, say, id and then do the update.

Otherwise, check this out:

```
 UPDATE Table 
 SET Field = Whatever     
 WHERE id = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM Highscore ORDER BY Score ASC)
```